# Rails same file name for different classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Having model Price (models/price.rb)

```
class Price
end
```

Also in lib directory I have import/detector/price.rb file

```
class Import::Detector::Price
end
```

Lib directory added to autoload paths via

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

So running Price.new I get error

Unable to autoload constant Price, expected lib/import/detector/price.rb to define it.

Import::Detector::Price.new is ok

What was my mistake?

**UPD.**
The most interesting

Also having this file models/car/property/price.rb

```
class Car::Property::Price
end
```

And everything ok with it. Car::Property::Price is available.

Comment: what is the output if you do this: `$ rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'`

Comment: lib directory and everything in it (long list) + http://pastebin.com/MwjYm7bH

Comment: I don't see a lib directory in the output you pasted, are you sure you have lib directory listed there? See my answer and let me know if it worked.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/W83VBABV

Comment: Roger, that behaviour is expected. As long as you are not in the module `Import::Detector`, you need to use the fully qualified constant. Please state in your Question from what context you are trying to use `Price` without prefix.

Comment: Can you show where you are calling Price.new from?

Comment: Ah sorry, I think I misunderstood at first. Try calling `::Price.new` to instantiate your model class. The double colon will make sure Ruby will not try to use `Import::Detector::Price`.

Comment: as Price is regular rails model I want to be able to call Price.new from anywhere where models are available. ::Price.new produce same error Unable to autoload constant Price

Comment: for now, I'm calling Price.new in rails console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib"]
```

instead of

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Using **, Dir will return every directory under lib and will put them all (as root directories) in the load path. It should only be the main lib directory in the load path as rails will work out the subdirectories using the namespace.

[Rails autoloading — how it works, and when it doesn't](http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/)

Comment: Thanks. That helps. But now something weird happens. I call Price.new - it's ok. But then I call Import::Detector::Price.new and get this warning: toplevel constant Price referenced by Import::Detector::Price. And instead of instance of Import::Detector::Price I get instance of my Price class.

Comment: In `Import::Detector::Price` are you referencing `Price`? Could you provide the contents of `Import::Detector::Price` especially where `Price` is mentioned?

Comment: There are no mentions of Price class in Import::Detector::Price because Price class was created only today. I have been using my Import::Detector::Price for several months and have no problems until today. Here my Import::Detector::Price http://pastebin.com/DHaaMcwi . It has only mention of Car::Property::Price class, but there are no problems with it. Import::Detector also has no mentions of Price. And one more thing to say. I have that warning only if I instantiate Price.new and then call Import::Detector::Price.new. If I call Import::Detector::Price.new first - there is no warning.

Comment: Here is the some screenshot to illustrate the problem http://i.imgur.com/ysmOIXs.png

Comment: I've just created the same structure in a Rails 4.2 app and I can't cause that error to show. That's with `Price` in app/models/price.rb, `Import::Detector::Price` in lib/import/detector/price.rb and `Car::Property::Price` in app/models/car/property/price.rb. It might be worth starting a new app and seeing if you get the same error there. If not then there might be something else in the app causing it.

Comment: Ok. May well be something wrong with rest of my project. Thanks for help with my original problem.